# "Not a thing" versus "nothing"

Tags: difference, usage

> "It's very kind of you to look after the baby all day."
>   "Oh, that's all right, it was ***nothing***, I enjoy it."

In this case, could **nothing** be replaced by **not a thing**? What's the difference between **nothing** and **not a thing** in general?

Comment: No, you often can't replace **nothing** with **not a thing**, such as in this case. All of the examples I can think of where you could are when either "nothing" or "thing" is the subject of a subordinate clause, but even then **nothing** can be used where **not a thing** can't. @StoneyB will likely be able to provide a clearer rule.

Answer (score 3):

I think that "not a thing" is used for specifically referring to an actual set of items, whereas in your example it is not.

In these sentences, I have replaced "nothing" with "not a thing".

> Correct: *Not a thing* was stolen when I left the shop unlocked.
>
> Correct: *Not a thing* is preventing someone from getting in.
>
> Incorrect: I've installed a new lock for you. Don't thank me; it was *not a thing.*

I feel that "nothing" in the context of politely refusing praise cannot be replaced by "not a thing".

Side note:

> "not a thing" can be expanded to "not a single a thing" and "not even a single thing" for emphasis.

Comment: In the context of the O.P.'s quote, "it was nothing" is almost idiomatic. I agree with you 100% that "it was not a thing" won't work in that context; however, there are a few acceptable alternatives, such as: "it wasn't anything" or, "it was no trouble at all."

Comment: Very true! For that purpose, I suppose honorable mention should be given to "It ain't no thang." as a very colloquial substitute.

Comment: Wow! You guys expanded my horizon. I never heard of "It ain't no thang." And @J.R. i prefer using "it was no trouble at all" cause it's a cordial answer.